# Mysql query that handles both a tagging system and favorites

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not really a developer but I'm developing an app as a side project and have become stumped with an SQL query I'm attempting to tackle. This app has collections of images that are tagged. My table structure looks something like this:

```
images
------
image
path

tag_map
------
image
tag

tags
-------
tag
tag_name

favorites
-------
user
image
```

My query is working well for the tagging system, however, I am not succeeding in adding a query for the favorites. Currently my query looks like this:

```
     SELECT i.*, IF (c.image IS NOT NULL,1,0) as favorited
        FROM (images i, tag_map m, tags t)
   LEFT JOIN favorites as c ON c.image = i.image
       WHERE m.tag = t.tag
         AND (t.tag_name IN ('umbrella'))
         AND i.image = m.image
         AND c.image = i.image
    GROUP BY i.image
      HAVING COUNT( i.image ) = 1
```

While this query works, it excludes rows that do note have an entry in the favorites table. The following simplified (sans tag system) query works:

```
 SELECT i.*, c.*,
        IF(c.image IS NOT NULL,1,0) as fave
   FROM (images as i)
   LEFT JOIN collection as c ON c.image = i.image
```

Any suggestions or points in the right direction would be awesome! Thanks!

Comment: We stopped using the archaic syntax back in 1992. Come. JOIN us.

Comment: Sorry, which part of the query is archaic?

Comment: There was a clue in my comment

Answer (score 1):

As it would turn out, my query works fine once I removed the superfluous *"AND c.image = i.image"* I had inadvertently left in there.

The working query is:

```
SELECT i.*, IF (c.image IS NOT NULL,1,0) as favorited
    FROM (images i, tag_map m, tags t)
    LEFT JOIN collections as c ON c.image = i.image
   WHERE m.tag = t.tag
     AND (t.tag_name IN ('umbrella'))
     AND i.image = m.image
GROUP BY i.image
  HAVING COUNT( i.image ) = 1
```